# Как правильно реализовать запись в файл работы функции?

Tags: python

На досуге, чтобы изучать питон, пишу эмулятор командной строки ДОС на питоне. Возник вопрос как правильно реализовать аналог ДОС команды утилита>файл. Сохранение результата работы в файл. Пример `dir>1.txt` Вариант `os.system('dir>1.txt')` конечно простой. Но я не для того занимаюсь извращениями чтоб было просто. Хочу чтоб в файл писал именно питон. Пока все это состоит из скрипта main который содержит вечный цикл ввода команд и модуля с функциями, которые main дергает в зависимости от введенной команды. 
Это main:

```
import utils
import os
import re


functions = {'tree': utils.tree, #словарь релизованных функций
             'quit': utils.quit, 'exit': utils.quit, 'x': utils.quit,
             'dir': utils.dir, 'ls': utils.dir,
             'cd': utils.cd, 'chdir':utils.cd,
             'help': utils.help, '?': utils.help,
             'cls':utils.cls
             }

while True:
    input_string = input(os.getcwd() + '>').lower() # читаем ввод
    cli = re.split(r'([a-z]+)(.*)', input_string)   # режем на функцию и аргумент
    cli.extend(' '' ')
    function_name = cli[1]
    argument = cli[2]
    if function_name in functions and argument == '/?': # если /? печатаем докум.
        print(functions[function_name].__doc__)
    elif function_name in functions:
        functions[function_name]((argument).strip()) # если функция в словаре - вызываем
        print('\n')
    elif function_name != ' ' or not function_name.isalpha(): 
        print(function_name + argument, """ не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.""")
```

Это пример функции из utils.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os
import datetime
import re

def cd(argument):
    r"""Вывод имени либо смена текущего каталога.
Здесь вырезано куча текста из справки

"""
    if len(argument) > 0:
        command = re.split(r'[ ]', argument, maxsplit=1)
        if len(command) > 1 and command[0] == '/d':
                path = command[1]
        else:
            path = argument
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            print('Системе не удается найти указанный путь.')
        else:
            accert: os.path.isdir(path)
            os.chdir(path)
    elif argument == '':
            print(os.getcwd())
```

Хотелось бы сделать так же просто как вывод справки если аргумент функции /?. Или надо переписать как-то функции чтоб они не печатали результат, а возвращали список строк, а потом его в зависимости от команды печатать в консоль или в файл писать? Прошу в пианиста не стрелять, играет как может. Опыта у меня нет совсем и именно чтоб его получить я эту бесполезную вещь и пишу.

Comment: Да, ввод пока никак не проверяется на хитрые некорректные комбинации и тд. И баги выскакивают постоянно. Все в процессе.

Comment: Если вы хотите перенаправить поток вывода, значит надо использовать модель процесса с потоком ввода, вывода и ошибок.

Comment: Т. Е. Функция не выводит на экран, а пишет в поток вывода, который может быть консолью или файлом и т. П.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import utils
import os
import re
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

functions = {'tree': utils.tree,
             'quit': utils.quit, 'exit': utils.quit, 'x': utils.quit,
             'dir': utils.dir, 'ls': utils.dir,
             'cd': utils.cd, 'chdir':utils.cd,
             'help': utils.help, '?': utils.help,
             'cls':utils.cls
             }

while True:
    input_string = input(os.getcwd() + '>').lower()
    cli = re.split(r'([a-z]+)(.*)', input_string)
    cli.extend(' '' ')
    function_name = cli[1]
    argument = cli[2]
    if function_name in functions and argument == '/?':
        print(functions[function_name].__doc__)



    elif function_name in functions and (len(argument) and argument[0] == '>'):
        with open(argument[1:], 'w') as file: #Перенаправляем вывод в файл если 
            with redirect_stdout(file):       #Аргумент начинается с '>'
                functions[function_name]('') 



    elif function_name in functions:
        functions[function_name]((argument).strip())
        print('\n')
    elif function_name != ' ' or not function_name.isalpha(): 
        print(function_name + argument, """ не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.""")
```

Comment: Конечно же надо еще прикрутить проверку символов после '>' на валидность при использовании в имени файла.